# Past Simple / Present perfect - is there any difference in meaning here?

Tags: tense

> 1 Lately, I have been playing a lot of App Games on my phone, and one
> of them **has been** Clash of Clans!
>
> 2 Lately, I have been playing a lot of App Games on my phone, and one
> of them **was** Clash of Clans!

I construe that 1 can mean that the speaker has played it more than once 2 means that they came across it (played) only once.

Comment: The difference between present perfect and simple past is dealt with extensively in various places, including this site (which even has [a tag](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/past-vs-present-perfect) dedicated to it). If you want to ask about that topic, then, you should demonstrate that you've already done research in at least some of those sources and explain what you've found.

Comment: I am not asking about the whole topic. I came up with a specific context. If you read my question more carefully you will see that I provided the explanation of how I see the difference. I am not going to write all I know about the tenses, it's simply uncalled.

Comment: I did indeed read your question carefully. However, the reason why you "construe" those things is entirely unclear to me. You don't need to explain everything you know about present perfect vs. simple past, but you really should explain why you think that one implies "more than once" and the other implies "only once". Your reasoning is not clear at all.

Comment: The present perfect shows that the person is still playing the game or is going to play in the future. For a one-off action the past simple fits best. If you have any explanation as to the difference between the two, go ahead and give it (to me). If you don't know the difference yourself, thank me for posting the question.

Comment: I think that few, if any native speakers would make that distinction, and I find version (1) unidiomatic.

Comment: version 1 is exactly the one which was produced by a native speaker in a video on youtibe